# Excecute function in Javascript when the event does not occur

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" onblur="numericField(this);" />
```

But I also need to excecute `numericField()` for the element before the form is submitted.
I tried `document.getElementById("Campo1").onblur()` but it returns `undefined`. How can I do this?

Comment: What if the user remains focussed and presses enter to submit the form?

Comment: Call the function `numericField(document.getElementById("add_an_id"))`

Comment: `element.blur()` emits the event and it also returns `undefined` because simply the native code does not return anything.

Comment: @ToddMotto That is why I need to run the validation function in onSubmit event.

Comment: @Christoph `element.blur()` returns `undefined` too

Comment: I'd recommend using unobtrusive JS approach so you can manage your validation external to your HTML.

Comment: @AlexK. I hava many elements in the form with differents validations so I can't do that.

Comment: The html code is generated by PHP so this is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: @Overflow012 and what's the problem with this method returning undefined?

Comment: @Christoph I need to run the validations and get true or false

Comment: That has nothing to do that the `blur()` method returns undefined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, binding events the way you do it is not a good idea. Instead, use `element.addEventListener` instead.

Guessing from your question you want to do a validation right before you submit the form. In this case you should write:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(){

  // validate your fields - basically run numericField() on both your input fields
  // if your numericField correctly returns true or false, the submit element will
  // be canceled if validation fails
  return numericField(your_element);
});
```

If you really wont to emit the blur event on a specific element, you can do the following:

```
var el = document.querySelector("<select your element here>");
el.focus();
el.blur();
```

Also with HTML5 you can now do a direct validation of the imput field on blur with defining the type correctly (e.g. if it's a Number set the type to number) and/or the `pattern` attribute [(Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2FInput). Now the browser intrinsic validation directly triggers on blur.

Comment: I need to run the validations and get true or false.

Comment: @Overflow012 yes, that is exactly what I describe in my answer.

Comment: @Overflow012 have you actually tried something of what I described in my answer?

Comment: @Overflow What exactly have you tried and what does "does not work" mean?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to do something before submit I suggest writting a validation function. It is much more transparent.
Example: JQuery

```
<form id="form">
...
</form>
```

You can use the following jQuery code to do something before the form is submitted:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        // DO STUFF
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });
});
```

Comment: I do the validations while the user fill the fields. It is more "user friendly". But I also need validate in onsubmit event.